# Get the keys from dictionary

Tags: json, powershell, dictionary

Please help.I need a list of all ARN's (arn:aws:ec2:a,arn:aws:ec2:b,arn:aws:ec2:c) from the below dictionary using powershell.

```
{
    "ResourceTagMappingList": [
        {
            "ResourceARN": "arn:aws:ec2:a",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "Amazon Linux Golden AMI"
                }

            ]
        },
        {
            "ResourceARN": "arn:aws:ec2:b",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "Windows 2016 Golden AMI"
                },
        },
        {
            "ResourceARN": "arn:aws:ec2:c",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "Amazon Linux Golden AMI"
                },
        }
}
```

Comment: The JSON you've posted is invalid/unbalanced, but `(Convert-FromJson $jsonString).ResourceTagMappingList.ResourceARN` should do the trick assuming you've just removed some list elements

Comment: mathias-r-jessen  - Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you get the json correct (missing some ] and has some extra commas), the following will work:

```
$x=Get-content File.json -raw | convertfrom-json
$x.ResourceTagMappingList.ResourceARN
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, I cant thank you enough for quick response. I've been struggling since 4 hours to get this done :) ,thank you so much again.